# struts 1.1 - How to set the property of html:submit through JS

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts-1

I have a form with a submit button in my Struts 1.1 JSP file:

```html
<html:form ...>
    <html:submit onclick="onupload();"> 
        Upload
    </html:submit>
</html:form>
```

Now, I want to change the value of `submit` button in `onupload()` function.
In regular HTML, I do it using `document.getElementByName`, but in `html:submit` tag the attribute `name` is not defined. So, I don't know how to change the value of button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `styleName` or `styleId` attributes to set the submit tag's name or id respectively.

These attributes are documented in the taglib documentation.